# Determining the maximum sum of elements among M groups with N elements

Tags: arrays

You are given an integer array a of size n and an integer m. you have to distribute the elements of array A into M groups such that the maximum sum of elements in each group is minimum and the elements of array A allocated to any group is contiguous. Write a program to determine the maximum sum of elements among all the groups.

Answer (score 0):

The brute force could be having all the M possible sub-arrays from the given array and checking with them. But this would take a time complexity of O(n^3).

Here I used dynamic programming which would take both the time and space complexity of O(n*M).

Try all the possible partitions that are possible using recursion. Let dp[ind][k] be the minimum of maximum sums till index 'ind' with 'k' partitions. Hence the possible states will be partition at every index from the index ind till n. The minimum of maximum sums of all those states will be our answer.
In order not to recur for visited element, we can use memoize.

Below is the implementation of the above approach:

```
from sys import maxsize
from sys import setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(10**6)


def max_sum_groups_min(arr, n, ind, M, dp):

    # If M segments have been divided
    if M == -1:
        # If we are at the end
        if ind == n:
            return -maxsize
        # If we do not reach end, return a maximum number 
        # that cannot be a min value than existing answer
        return maxsize

    # If at the end, but M segmments are not formed
    if ind == n:
        return maxsize

    # If it's already visited: Memoization
    if dp[ind][M] != False:
        return dp[ind][M]

    ans = maxsize
    cur = 0

    # Iterate and try to break at every segment and create a segment
    for i in range(ind, n):
        # sum of elements in current segment
        cur += arr[i]

        # Find the maximum of all segments after adding and
        # find minimum in all possible combinations
        ans = min(ans, max(max_sum_groups_min(arr, n, i + 1, M - 1, dp), cur))

    # Return the answer by memoizing it
    dp[ind][M] = ans
    return ans


n = int(input("Enter array size: "))
arr = list(map(int, input("Enter list of elements: ").split()))
group = int(input("Enter the group size: "))

# keeping 'False' inorder to keep track it's not visited
dp = [[False for _ in range(group)] for _ in range(n)]

print(max_sum_groups_min(arr, n, 0, group - 1, dp))
```

For eg: n = 8, arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], M = 4

Here the given array can be divided into 4 groups as:
{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7}, {8}
in which 2nd group has largest sum(11) among all the groups which is minimum of all possibilities.

Thanks,
Jayanth.